# Hadoop Datanode won't start on master node [Debian 11]

Tags: hadoop, datanode

I am trying to install and use Hadoop for my thesis, however I encountered a problem that I cannot fix. When I use the **start-dfs.sh** or **start-all.sh** script, it appears that the datanode on the master node does not start. I have confirmed that with the `Jps` command. Also the log files inside *${HADOOP_HOME}/logs* are empty. What I have tried so far is deleting the datanode folder and formatting the namenode without success and manually start the datanode with `hdfs datanode` which works but is there any other fix so that it can start with the other daemons? Thank you.

Comment: If `${HADOOP_HOME}/logs` are empty then either log4j.properties is not configured, or logs are written somewhere else. Its hard to answer why something is failing without logs.

Comment: If you don't need a cluster, and just want to run both locally, you could use Docker https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L3-L19 ; or if you do want a cluster, using AWS EMR or Google DataProc would be far easier

Comment: @OneCricketeer only hadoop-hadoop-datanode-master.log file is empty
the others are not.

Comment: @OneCricketeer the point is to install and set it up by myself locally. One master node and two workers.

Comment: There's no such thing as Master and workers for HDFS. You mean namenode and datanodes? Have you tried using a different version of Hadoop? What Java version are you using? Have you looking at using Apache Bigtop rather than doing installation manually? Also, Docker should still work fine for your purposes

Comment: "Hadoop clusters are composed of a network of master and worker nodes that orchestrate and execute the various jobs across the Hadoop distributed file system. The master nodes typically utilize higher quality hardware and include a NameNode, Secondary NameNode, and JobTracker, with each running on a separate machine. The workers consist of virtual machines, running both DataNode and TaskTracker services on commodity hardware, and do the actual work of storing and processing the jobs as directed by the master nodes."

Comment: I am using Java version 11. I used to read comments about spark and java 11 not working properly but everything was working perfectly untill the time I created the two worker nodes. Something in the hdfs configuration created that problem and Im trying to find it.

Comment: TaskTracker/JobTracker don't exist anymore. You're reading old documentation. And if you're reading old documentation, and have downloaded an old hadoop version, then Java 11 probably wouldn't work. Like I said, you should look at installing Hadoop and related components through solutions like Apache Bigtop if you need to manage your own cluster.

Comment: Do you have anything that can help me get start with Bigtop?

Comment: Other than the official website itself, I do not